# Taxonomy Terms mapping Many to one mapping | Complex

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I have a typical / complex task and need help. this is with related to taxonomy terms and creating many to many kind of relations but without duplicating the terms, please see this excel sheet for sample data

http://demo.bodhtree.com/category-sub-category-mapping.xlsx

any guidance from community is highly appreciated.

Comment: Each term has one unique field - id. And what u eant is not a taxonomy

Comment: Your excel file is not clear what you are asking. Embed a picture of your data structure in your question

Comment: @Drupalist i think he wants some taxonomy terms to be used by different vocabularies physically

Comment: @ar7max from what I understand he should use entity reference instead of taxonomy

Comment: @Drupalist agree